# How to add Salesforce Inbox in Scratch Org definition

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, inbox

How do we add Salesforce Inbox in our scratch org definition file?

I'm trying to build a 2GP, in which I have a permission set group that is referencing the following permission set - force__InboxWithoutEinsteinActivityCapture.

However I don't have it in the scratch org, resulting in an error - Missing the PS.

I have tried with Org Shape also, but to no success.

The features I've added are :

````
     , "ProcessBuilder", "LightningSalesConsole", "InsightsPlatform"
     , "OrderManagement", "Chatbot", "EinsteinVisits"
     , "EinsteinRecommendationBuilderMetadata", "EinsteinRecommendationBuilder", "EinsteinBuilderFree"
     , "EinsteinArticleRecommendations", "EinsteinAnalyticsPlus"
     , "SalesUser", "MultiCurrency", "StateAndCountryPicklist"
     , "SalesCloudEinstein", "ContactsToMultipleAccounts"] ```

And for the Settings, I have pulled them via MetadataAPI and recreated them.

"settings": {
         "ActivitiesSettings": {
            "enableActivityReminders": true,
            "enableClickCreateEvents": true,
            "enableDragAndDropScheduling": true,
            "enableEmailTracking": true,
            "enableGroupTasks": true,
            "enableListViewScheduling": true,
            "enableMultidayEvents": true,
            "enableRecurringEvents": true,
            "enableRecurringTasks": true,
            "enableRollUpActivToContactsAcct": true,
            "enableSimpleTaskCreateUI": true
         },
         "accountSettings":{
            "enableAccountTeams": true,
            "enableAccountHistoryTracking": true,
            "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
         },
         "opportunitySettings": {
               "enableOpportunityTeam": true
         },
         "actionsSettings": {
            "enableDefaultQuickActionsOn": true
         },
         "chatterSettings": {
            "enableChatter": true,
            "enableFeedEdit": true
         },
         "currencySettings": {
               "enableMultiCurrency": true
         },
         "caseSettings": {
               "enableCaseFeed": true
         },
         "EACSettings":{
            "enableInsightsInTimeline": true,
            "provisionProductivityFeatures": true
         },
         "enhancedNotesSettings": {
            "enableEnhancedNotes": true
         },
         "eventSettings": {
            "enableDeleteMonitoringData": true,
            "enableStreamingApi": true
         },
         "emailAdministration":{
            "enableEmailSenderIdCompliance": true,
            "enableEmailSpfCompliance": true,
            "enableEmailToSalesforce": true,
            "enableEnhancedEmailEnabled": true,
            "enableHandleBouncedEmails": true,
            "enableListEmailLogActivities": true,
            "enableSendViaExchangePref": true,
            "sendMassEmailNotification": true
         },
         "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableAuraCDNPref": true,
            "enableS1BannerPref": true,
            "enableInAppTooltips": true,
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "enableS1UiLoggingEnabled": true,
            "enableUsersAreLightningOnly": true
         },
         "orderSettings": {
               "enableOrders": true              
            },
            "quoteSettings": {
               "enableQuote": true              
            }
    }

Which feature am I lacking in order to get that permission set?
````

Comment: I have tried using org shape for the scratch org source, but had still the same issue.

The scratch org is created correctly, if you decide to create it and log in. But for the package generation it still couldnt find the permission set.

At the end i had to remove the reference as Salesforce suggest you assign the Inbox permissions manually - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318170&type=1&mode=1

Comment: I'm just trying to push my source without getting an error. My similar question with no answer is [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366090/how-to-programmatically-turn-on-einstein-email-tracking-settings-in-scratch-org)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (fwiw - I also am using shape-based org) insofar as it turned on the `Salesforce Inbox` feature and allows my source code to push successfully.

```
  "settings": 
  {
    ...
    "emailIntegrationSettings":{
      "enableContactAndEventSync": true,
      "enableProductivityFeatures": true,
      "doesGmailStayConnectedToSalesforce": true,
      "enableOutlookIntegration": true,
      "enableGmailIntegration": true,
      "isLayoutCustomizationAllowed": true,
      "doesEmailLogAsEmailMessageInOutlook": false,
      "shouldUseTrustedDomainsList": false,
      "enableEmailTrackingInMobile": true,
      "enableSupplementalContactInfoInMobile": false,
      "enableEngageForOutlook": true
    },
```

I'm noticing that these permission sets seemed to have been created:
[image: my scratch org permission sets]