# how to programmatically turn on Einstein email tracking settings in scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, einstein, email-tracking

##### EDIT: my question is prob a diff way to ask [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339397/how-to-add-salesforce-inbox-in-scratch-org-definition)

I get this error in my CLI when pushing source:

> In field: field - no CustomField named ListEmail.DeliveryRate

and I've discovered that the error is resolved if I

1. manually launch my scratch org and go into the setup
2. Navigate:
   `Einstein` > `Einstein Sales` > `Inbox` > `Setup Assistant`
3. Turn on `Make Inbox Available to Users`
4. Turn on `Email Tracking`

I'm already using a shape-based org - is there some technique to help me navigate this issue in a more automated CI-pipeline friendly way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me insofar as it turned on the `Salesforce Inbox` feature and turned on the email tracking checkbox - IDK how much of this is influenced by my org shape versus adding these settings below, I only know once I added this section is when it started to work properly

```
  "settings": 
  {
    ...
    "emailIntegrationSettings":{
      "enableContactAndEventSync": true,
      "enableProductivityFeatures": true,
      "doesGmailStayConnectedToSalesforce": true,
      "enableOutlookIntegration": true,
      "enableGmailIntegration": true,
      "isLayoutCustomizationAllowed": true,
      "doesEmailLogAsEmailMessageInOutlook": false,
      "shouldUseTrustedDomainsList": false,
      "enableEmailTrackingInMobile": true,
      "enableSupplementalContactInfoInMobile": false,
      "enableEngageForOutlook": true
    },
```

FWIW - I [copied the default values from the XML example shown on this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailintegrationsettings.htm)

[image: my salesforce inbox settings]
(I am about to push source and will update this answer if it indeed fully works as I expected)